# What type of messages does SQL Service Broker send?

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

SQL Server has Service Broker, which provides messaging and queueing functions between instances.

I am new to using this technology and want to know which kind of messages does it send between instances. I mean what information does it try to convey by sending a message, and how other instances understand the content of that message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*<sub>[Community wiki answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki): - please edit to improve</sub>*

The message payload can be virtually anything since the underlying queue `message_body` column is type `varbinary(MAX)`. It is most common to use XML though because Service Broker can enforce well-formed or schema-valid XML as part of the service contract.

Have a look at:

- [SQL Server Service Broker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-service-broker?view=sql-server-2017) in the product documentation; and
- [SQL Server Service Broker example on how to configure, send and receive messages](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1836/sql-server-service-broker-example-on-how-to-configure-send-and-receive-messages/) by Jayakumar Krishnan

They will help you to configure, send and receive Service Broker messages.